# Laravel rename file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to rename a file in laravel 5.6

This works fine when I'm physically renaming the file, but when I'm just changing case - It throws an error:

```
League\Flysystem\FileExistsException: File already exists at path
```

Example

```
old path: Music/The Corrs/The Corrs - What Can I Do.mp3
new path (DO): Music/The Corrs/The Corrs - What Can I DO.mp3
```

Code

```
Storage::disk($disk)->move($old, new);
```

How can I work around this so I can rename/move files if just the case is changing?

Comment: while storing file you can convert file name to either upper case or to lower case and do the same while renaming file.

Comment: @SalmanZafar I'd rather not convert the entire name. I need to keep the case as is.

Comment: Are you on windows or linux? On Windows, case doesn't matter for file names.

Comment: @Jerodev On Windows.

Not sure what you mean case doesn't matter? 

If I have a user that uploads a file as ALL IN UPPERCASE.mp3, but our 'policy' is to store it as something like 'All In Uppercase.mp3' then case does matter?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear. It is impossible to have two files with the same name in a folder and for windows the name `uppercase.txt` and `UPPERCASE.txt` are the same.

Comment: @Jerodev - That makes sense. So I'd have to move it to a temporary directory, then move it back to the "original" folder.

OK, that will be my problem, thank you.

If you want to stick that as an 'answer' rather than a comment I can accept it.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, case doesn't matter for file names. So files with the names `uppercase.txt` and `UPPERCASE.txt` are the same, but it is impossible to have two files with the same name in a folder.
When renaming, the file is actually "moved" to another name. However the file already exists, so you get an error.

I would recommend to store the files in a temp folder first to rename or use a temporary name for the files before renaming.

Comment: Op only needs to do two steps the same you need to do when renaming in explorer. First rename filename.file to _filename.file then rename it again to Filename.file. No need to really move it to a temp folder

Comment: Exactly, the temp folder and temp rename are two separate possible solutions. :)

Answer (score -1):

Off the cuff solution

```
$oldPath = "Music/The Corrs/The Corrs - What Can I Do.mp3";
$newPath = "Music/The Corrs/The Corrs - What Can I DO.mp3";
$paddedPath = str_replace(" ", "@@padding@@", $oldPath);

//move from old path to padded path
Storage::move(
   $oldPath, 
   $paddedPath, 

);

//move from padded path to new
Storage::move(
    $paddedPath, 
    $newPath
);
```